# How to merge 2 data frames with uneven length using keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames using keys from one data frame. The input files are .csv files, and I would like my output file to also be a .csv file.

My two input files look like this:

```
DF1:

Org1   Org2  
OTU_1  OTU_2
OTU_1  OTU 3
OTU_1  OTU_4
OTU_2  OTU_4

DF2:

Org1  Interaction  Ratio
OTU_1  TRUE   0.5
OTU_2  FALSE  0.1
```

I want my output file to look like this:

```
Org1  Org2  Interaction  Ratio
OTU_1  OTU_2  TRUE  0.5
OTU_1  OTU_3  TRUE  0.5
OTU_1  OTU_4  TRUE  0.5
OTU_2  OTU_4  FALSE 0.1
```

I have done the following:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import io
from io import StringIO

DF1=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(sys.argv[1].decode()),sep="[;,]",engine="python")
DF2=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(sys.argv[2].decode()),sep="[;,]",engine="python")


merged=pd.merge(DF1,DF2,how="left",on="Org1")

df.to_csv(merged,sep='\t')
```

I am receiving the following error:

KeyError: 'Org1'

Would greatly appreciate info on what to fix to get my desired output file.

Comment: KeyError means the either or both data frames don't have Org1 as column. Please update your post with fh1.columns and fh2.columns

Comment: Can you show us `fh1.columns` and  `fh2.columns` ?

Comment: sorry DF1 = fh1 and DF2=fh2.  The columns are those that I listed in my input data frames.  I will edit my question to reflect this. 

So, fh1.columns are 'Org1','Org2' and fh2.columns are 'Org1', 'Interaction', 'Ratio'

Comment: The error says there no column names `Org1` and that's why We need to see columns of both the dataframes. There can be a spelling mistake, case mismatch, extra white space etc in the column name. Please provide `DF1.columns` and `DF2.columns`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to show you the columns, I have added a photo of each of my files so you can see the column names. The word is in both files and doesn't seem to be any mismatch or extra white spaces

Comment: Do `print(DF1.columns)` and then paste the output. Do same for `DF2`

Comment: Sometimes when you read the data from csv, there are empty strings around the columns names. You can not detect them by looking at df.head() but printing df.columns can help you with the same. KeyError clearly means pandas can not find the column name on which you are trying to merge. Thats the reason we need to see df.columns

Comment: Thank you for these comments. something is clearly wrong. When I try print(DF1.columns) I get the following and not sure what it means:

Index([u'DF1.csv'], dtype='object')

Comment: So your real problem is how you are reading the data. Check your read_csv code

Comment: Yes I guess my real problem is that there is problem with my input file and something about the format being in unicode. I don't know how to solve this issue...

Comment: You can ask a new question with example of input file

Comment: Thank you all for your help, you helped me figure out that my actual problem was that I had to specify that keys should be of string type. By adding dtype=str to my pd.read_csv command, it fixed the issue and my code works as desired

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, I was able to resolve the issue with guidance from your comments.

The real error was that I needed to specify dtype=str in the pd.read_csv() command. Without this, python was unable to read my keys because it was unable to read my input files properly. I was also having errors with the way that I was trying to write my csv file, so overall, the code was just not working on several levels.

Posting the following code that works as intended.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import io
from io import StringIO


DF1=pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],dtype=str)
DF2=pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2],dtype=str)
Org=sys.argv[3]


merged=pd.merge(DF1,DF2,how="left",on=Org)
mergeddf=pd.DataFrame(merged)
mergeddf.to_csv(sys.argv[4],sep=";",encoding="utf-8")
```